# Auto increment in postgresql does not operate with imported data

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, csv, jupyter-notebook

ERROR:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.duplicate key value violates unique constraint "testing_pkey"

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "testing_pkey"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (id)=(2) already exists.

```
package com.groupproject.bookmarket.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "testing")
public class Testing {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long id;

    private String status;

}
```

I have created the above entity then imported data from a csv file or from jupyter notebook to postgresql then I tried to insert a row and the Error above appeared

How to make postgresql know that it had to take the biggest value of the id and increase it up. Or something like that or may I have mistaken something

Comment: This is a generic issue when importing data over existing data, you need to deal with conflicting data. What makes you think a row with the same id as an existing row can be 'fixed' by moving it out of the way by assigning it a different id?